# haystack-django: how to implement search suggestions when user starts to type query?

Tags: django, solr, django-haystack

I'm using Django==1.11.8, django-haystack==2.7.0, pysolr==3.7.0 and Solr==6.6.3 and Python3

Here is a model called `MainData` from which I want to show search results.

```
from django.db.models import *
from django.db import models as models


class MainData(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, editable=False)
    last_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, editable=False)
    url = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True, null=True)
    metadata = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
    meta_keywords = models.TextField(max_length=1000, blank=True, null=True)
    context = models.TextField(max_length=1000, blank=True, null=True)


    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-created',)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.title)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return self.url
```

my `search_index.py` file:

```
import datetime
from haystack import indexes
from .models import MainData


class MainSearchIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
    url = indexes.CharField(model_attr='url', null=True)
    title = indexes.EdgeNgramField(model_attr='title', null=True)
    metadata = indexes.EdgeNgramField(model_attr='metadata', null=True)
    meta_keywords = indexes.CharField(model_attr='meta_keywords', null=True)
    context = indexes.EdgeNgramField(model_attr='context', null=True)
    suggestions = indexes.FacetCharField()

    def get_model(self):
        return MainData

    def index_queryset(self, using=None):
        return MainData.objects.filter(created__lte=datetime.datetime.now())

    def prepare(self, obj):
        prepared_data = super(MainSearchIndex, self).prepare(obj)
        prepared_data['suggestions'] = prepared_data['text']
        return prepared_data
```

Now, my question is that how can I implement auto-suggestions feature like Google when a user starts to type something. I also want to implement spelling check feature.

Please help me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There are some good information about autocomplete on the haystack django documentation.

https://django-haystack.readthedocs.io/en/v2.7.0/autocomplete.html

Comment: I have read the documentation but I am having a hard time figuring out where to put views.py and HTML. If you can help me